# How can I remove an element from a list?

Tags: r, list, indexing, r-faq

I have a list and I want to remove a single element from it.  How can I do this?

I've tried looking up what I think the obvious names for this function would be in the reference manual and I haven't found anything appropriate.

Comment: Depends do you want to remove it by value e.g. "the value 5", or by index/indices "the element at index 5" or "at indices c(5:6,10)? If you want to remove by value and there are duplicates, then do you want to remove only the duplicates, first or last occurrence, or all? Is it guaranteed that the list contains your element/index? Do we need to handle the case where the list is empty? Do we need to ensure NA is passed (/excluded)? Is the list guaranteed to be flat or can it be nested? How many laters deep?

Comment: setdiff(myList,elementToRemove)

Answer (score 252, accepted):

I don't know R at all, but a bit of creative googling led me here: http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/05/04/1919.html

The key quote from there:

> I do not find explicit documentation for R on how to remove elements from lists, but trial and error tells me

> myList[[5]] <- NULL

> will remove the 5th element and then "close up" the hole caused by deletion of that element. That suffles the index values, So I have to be careful in dropping elements. I must work from the back of the list to the front.

A [response to that post later in the thread](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/05/04/1917.html) states:

> For deleting an element of a list, see R FAQ 7.1

And the [relevant section of the R FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-set-components-of-a-list-to-NULL_003f) says:

> ... Do not set x[i] or x[[i]] to NULL, because this will remove the corresponding component from the list.

Which seems to tell you (in a somewhat backwards way) how to remove an element.

Comment: Thanks, mylist[i] <- NULL is exactly the way to do it.

Comment: This did not work for me. I get: `Error in list[length(list)] <- NULL : replacement has length zero`

Comment: @Aleksandr Levchuck 's post showed me that I was actually dealing with a vector and needed to create a new object

Comment: This is a great shortcut, but it seems to me like @Kim's answer using `within` would be the "right" way to remove list elements, since it allows the use of character strings to identify list elements, can remove multiple elements simultaneously, and does not need to be done in place. Am I missing something (other than the fact that the OP's question was about removing a single element)? Thanks.

Answer (score 296):

If you don't want to modify the list in-place (e.g. for passing the list with an element removed to a function), you can use indexing: negative indices mean "don't include this element".

```
x <- list("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")  # example list

x[-2]        # without 2nd element

x[-c(2, 3)]  # without 2nd and 3rd
```

Also, logical index vectors are useful:

```
x[x != "b"]  # without elements that are "b"
```

This works with dataframes, too:

```
df <- data.frame(number = 1:5, name = letters[1:5])

df[df$name != "b", ]      # rows without "b"

df[df$number %% 2 == 1, ] # rows with odd numbers only
```

Comment: Your logical index only works if you have that single item "b" in a list element.  You cannot remove , say,   `x$b` that way, nor can you remove "b" from a list element `x[[2]] = c("b","k")`  .

Comment: Regarding single vs multiple items: you could use `%in%` for testing against multiple items. I’m not sure what you mean by “cannot remove x$b” – do you mean removing the whole column `b`?

Answer (score 69):

I would like to add that if it's a *named list* you can simply use `within`.

```
l <- list(a = 1, b = 2)    
> within(l, rm(a))
$b
[1] 2
```

So you can overwrite the original list

```
l <- within(l, rm(a))
```

to remove element named `a` from list `l`.

Comment: To do multiple `within(l, rm(a, b))`

Comment: To do multiple from a character vector: `x <- c("a","b"); within(l,rm(list=x))`

Answer (score 40):

Here is how the remove the last element of a **list** in R:

```
x <- list("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
x[length(x)] <- NULL
```

If x might be a vector then you would need to create a new object:

```
x <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
x <- x[-length(x)]
```

- Work for **lists** and **vectors**

Comment: @krlmlr: on the contrary, this solution is more general than Florian's answer, as it is polymorphic in the type of the collection.

Comment: @DanBarowy: I was wrong: This seems to be a synthesis of Chad's answer (the accepted one) and Florian's... A good brief summary, though.

Answer (score 23):

Removing Null elements from a list in single line :

`x=x[-(which(sapply(x,is.null),arr.ind=TRUE))]`

Cheers

Comment: This code breaks when `x` is an empty list.  Use `compact` from `plyr` for this task instead.

Comment: Also if there are no nulls in the list, `-(which(sapply(x,is.null),arr.ind=TRUE))` returns `named integer(0)` which will drop that row entirely.

Answer (score 19):

If you have a named list and want to remove a specific element you can try:

```
lst <- list(a = 1:4, b = 4:8, c = 8:10)

if("b" %in% names(lst)) lst <- lst[ - which(names(lst) == "b")]
```

This will make a list `lst` with elements `a`, `b`, `c`. The second line removes element `b` after it checks that it exists (to avoid the problem @hjv mentioned).

or better:

```
lst$b <- NULL
```

This way it is not a problem to try to delete a non-existent element (e.g. `lst$g <- NULL`)

Answer (score 16):

Use `-` (Negative sign) along with position of element, example if 3rd element is to be removed use it as `your_list[-3]`

**Input**

```
my_list <- list(a = 3, b = 3, c = 4, d = "Hello", e = NA)
my_list
# $`a`
# [1] 3

# $b
# [1] 3

# $c
# [1] 4

# $d
# [1] "Hello"

# $e
# [1] NA
```

**Remove single element from list**

```
 my_list[-3]
 # $`a`
 # [1] 3

 # $b
 # [1] 3

 # $d
 # [1] "Hello"

 # $e
 [1] NA
```

**Remove multiple elements from list**

```
 my_list[c(-1,-3,-2)]
 # $`d`
 # [1] "Hello"

 # $e
 # [1] NA
```

---

```
 my_list[c(-3:-5)]
 # $`a`
 # [1] 3

 # $b
 # [1] 3
```

---

```
 my_list[-seq(1:2)]
 # $`c`
 # [1] 4

 # $d
 # [1] "Hello"

 # $e
 # [1] NA
```

Answer (score 11):

There's the rlist package (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlist/index.html) to deal with various kinds of list operations.

Example (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlist/vignettes/Filtering.html):

```
library(rlist)
devs <- 
  list(
    p1=list(name="Ken",age=24,
      interest=c("reading","music","movies"),
      lang=list(r=2,csharp=4,python=3)),
    p2=list(name="James",age=25,
      interest=c("sports","music"),
      lang=list(r=3,java=2,cpp=5)),
    p3=list(name="Penny",age=24,
      interest=c("movies","reading"),
      lang=list(r=1,cpp=4,python=2)))

list.remove(devs, c("p1","p2"))
```

Results in:

```
# $p3
# $p3$name
# [1] "Penny"
# 
# $p3$age
# [1] 24
# 
# $p3$interest
# [1] "movies"  "reading"
# 
# $p3$lang
# $p3$lang$r
# [1] 1
# 
# $p3$lang$cpp
# [1] 4
# 
# $p3$lang$python
# [1] 2
```

Comment: how could one remove the python or lang items in this example?

Answer (score 9):

Don't know if you still need an answer to this but I found from my limited (3 weeks worth of self-teaching R) experience with R that, using the `NULL` assignment is actually wrong or sub-optimal especially if you're dynamically updating a list in something like a for-loop.

To be more precise, using

```
myList[[5]] <- NULL
```

will throw the error

> myList[[5]] <- NULL : replacement has length zero

or

> more elements supplied than there are to replace

What I found to work more consistently is

```
myList <- myList[[-5]]
```

Comment: Good answer! However, I think the `[[-5]]` should be single square brackets, otherwise you are deselecting only the contents of that list element, not the element itself. Well, at least using double square brackets gives me this error: "attempt to select more than one element". What works for me was then: `myList <- myList[-5]`.

Answer (score 7):

Just wanted to quickly add (because I didn't see it in any of the answers) that, for a named list, you can also do `l["name"] <- NULL`. For example:

```
l <- list(a = 1, b = 2, cc = 3)
l['b'] <- NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

In the case of named lists I find those helper functions useful

```
member <- function(list,names){
    ## return the elements of the list with the input names
    member..names <- names(list)
    index <- which(member..names %in% names)
    list[index]    
}


exclude <- function(list,names){
     ## return the elements of the list not belonging to names
     member..names <- names(list)
     index <- which(!(member..names %in% names))
    list[index]    
}  
aa <- structure(list(a = 1:10, b = 4:5, fruits = c("apple", "orange"
)), .Names = c("a", "b", "fruits"))

> aa
## $a
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

## $b
## [1] 4 5

## $fruits
## [1] "apple"  "orange"


> member(aa,"fruits")
## $fruits
## [1] "apple"  "orange"


> exclude(aa,"fruits")
## $a
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

## $b
## [1] 4 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Using lapply and grep:

```
lst <- list(a = 1:4, b = 4:8, c = 8:10)
# say you want to remove a and c
toremove<-c("a","c")
lstnew<-lst[-unlist(lapply(toremove, function(x) grep(x, names(lst)) ) ) ]
# or
pattern<-"a|c"
lstnew<-lst[-grep(pattern, names(lst))]
# or
lst %>% purrr::discard(names(.) == "a") # use %in% for a set
```

Comment: thanks for a solution using the tidyverse!

Answer (score 2):

You can also negatively index from a list using the `extract` function of the `magrittr` package to remove a list item.

```
a <- seq(1,5)
b <- seq(2,6)
c <- seq(3,7)
l <- list(a,b,c)

library(magrittr)

extract(l,-1) #simple one-function method
[[1]]
[1] 2 3 4 5 6

[[2]]
[1] 3 4 5 6 7
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to remove the first occurrence of the element `"b"` and leave the rest

```r
x <- c("a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "e")

which(x == "b")
# [1] 2 3

which(x == "b")[1]
# [1] 2

x[-which(x == "b")[1]]
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

Comment: This only works if the list has a "b" item

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options in the `purrr` package that haven't been mentioned:

`pluck` and `assign_in` work well with nested values and you can access it using a combination of names and/or indices:

```
library(purrr)

l <- list("a" = 1:2, "b" = 3:4, "d" = list("e" = 5:6, "f" = 7:8))

# select values (by name and/or index)
all.equal(pluck(l, "d", "e"), pluck(l, 3, "e"), pluck(l, 3, 1))
[1] TRUE

# or if element location stored in a vector use !!!
pluck(l, !!! as.list(c("d", "e")))
[1] 5 6

# remove values (modifies in place)
pluck(l, "d", "e") <- NULL

# assign_in to remove values with name and/or index (does not modify in place)
assign_in(l, list("d", 1), NULL)
$a
[1] 1 2

$b
[1] 3 4

$d
$d$f
[1] 7 8
```

Or you can remove values using `modify_list` by assigning `zap()` or `NULL`:

```
all.equal(list_modify(l, a = zap()), list_modify(l, a = NULL))
[1] TRUE
```

You can remove or keep elements using a predicate function with `discard` and `keep`:

```
# remove numeric elements
discard(l, is.numeric)
$d
$d$e
[1] 5 6

$d$f
[1] 7 8

# keep numeric elements
keep(l, is.numeric)
$a
[1] 1 2

$b
[1] 3 4
```

Comment: `pluck(l, "d", "e") <- NULL` worked for me. I tried something like `names(list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)[c("b", "c")])` to get rid  of `a`, but in my shiny app i got `NA, b, c`. Your `pluck` statement actually deleted the `a` value. Thanks!

Comment: @captinbo I am not clear what you're trying to do. `names(list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)[c("b", "c")])` returns `"b" "c"`. If you're trying to remove `a` then you can assign it `NULL`, or select the other elements that are not `a`.

Comment: yes, it returns "b", "c", which is what I'm trying to do. But oddly, in my R Shiny app it was returning `"NA", "b", "c"` during runtime. I spent an hour on that bug trying different ways to subset my list to the elements I wanted, but only your `pluck` method worked. It was very odd that I was getting a list with the name `NA` in it.

Comment: @captinbo this would be a good SO question if you could make a small reproducible example and post it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution that can be done using base R. It removes the number 5 from the original list of numbers. You can use the same method to remove whatever element you want from a list.

```
#the original list
original_list = c(1:10)

#the list element to remove
remove = 5

#the new list (which will not contain whatever the `remove` variable equals)
new_list = c()

#go through all the elements in the list and add them to the new list if they don't equal the `remove` variable
counter = 1
for (n in original_list){
  if (n != ){
    new_list[[counter]] = n
    counter = counter + 1
  }
}
```

The `new_list` variable no longer contains 5.

```
new_list
# [1]  1  2  3  4  6  7  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that **'remove'** means making it **'NULL'** without changing the overall order.

```
mylist <- list("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")

# remove rule (or)
# 1. remove letter "e" & "f"
# 2. remove the 2nd value

mapply(
  \(x, y) if (x %in% c("e", "f") | y == 2) { NULL } else { x },
  mylist,
  1:length(mylist)
)

# output:
# [[1]]
# [1] "a"
# 
# [[2]]
# NULL
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "c"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "d"
# 
# [[5]]
# NULL
# 
# [[6]]
# NULL
# 
# [[7]]
# [1] "g"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `which`.

```
x<-c(1:5)
x
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
x<-x[-which(x==4)]
x
#[1] 1 2 3 5
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this? Again, using indices

```
> m <- c(1:5)
> m
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

> m[1:length(m)-1]
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

or

```
> m[-(length(m))]
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: m is a vector, not a list

Comment: The method does work for lists, but OP is lucky and probably wants some more parentheses: `m[1:(length(m) - 1)]`

Answer (score -1):

if you'd like to avoid numeric indices, you can use

```
a <- setdiff(names(a),c("name1", ..., "namen"))
```

to delete names `namea...namen` from a.  this works for lists

```
> l <- list(a=1,b=2)
> l[setdiff(names(l),"a")]
$b
[1] 2
```

as well as for vectors

```
> v <- c(a=1,b=2)
> v[setdiff(names(v),"a")]
b 
2
```