# R: How can I remove rows from all the data frames in this list?

Tags: r

Say I have some data created like this

```
n <- 3
K <- 4
dat <- expand.grid(var1=1:n, var2=1:K)
```

dat looks like this:

```
    var1    var2
1     1      1
2     2      1
3     3      1
4     1      2
5     2      2
6     3      2 
7     1      3
8     2      3
9     3      3
10    1      4
11    2      4
12    3      4
```

I want to remove some rows from both data frames in the list at the same time. Let's say I want to remove the 11th row, and I want the 'gap' to be filled in, so that now the 12th row will become the 11th row.

I understand this is a list of two data frames. Thus the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652136/how-can-i-remove-an-element-from-a-list) does not apply, since `dat[[11]]<-NULL` would do nothing, while `dat[[2]]<-NULL` would remove the second data frame from the list

`lapply(dat,"[",11)` lets me access the relevant elements, but I don't know how to remove them.

Comment: When I enter typeof(dat) it says "list". The code above is everything I have. I don't have any other data frames in my environment.

Comment: dat[-11,] removes a row, but then it leaves a gap whereby we skip from 10 to 12. I need a process that removes rows but leaves no gap.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Maybe I the question was titled inaccurately, since when I wrote the question I was under the mistaken impression that dat was a list.

Comment: I would check `str(dat)` to understand the structure of the dataset.  If it is a `list`, `str(list(dat, dat))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that we want to remove rows from a `list` of `data.frame`s, we loop the `list` elements using `lapply` and remove the rows using numeric index.

```
lapply(lst, function(x) x[-11,])
```

Or without the anonymous function

```
lapply(lst, `[`, -11,)
```

The 'dat' is a `data.frame`.

```
is.data.frame(dat)
#[1] TRUE
```

If we want to remove rows from 'dat',

```
dat[-11,]
```

If the row.names also needs to be changed

```
`row.names<-`(dat[-11,], NULL)
```

#### data

```
lst <- list(dat, dat)
```