# Unpack a list into a data.frame/data.table

Tags: r, list

I have a list of `data.frames`. Each has the same two columns. I need to unlist it into a single data.frame. I have tried multiple things (including `unlist`, converting to a matrix, etc. — including from some of the SO searches that come up first), but I am having trouble making it work (the `unlist` command just generates a bunch of columns, while I need two columns and a bunch of rows).

I ended up writing a `for` loop this instance, but it’s a problematic approach for well-known reasons.

Here is the data and my current approach:

```
> head(dotz, 2)
[[1]]
          X1       X2
1  -83.06974 42.32464
2  -83.06155 42.32168
3  -83.06034 42.32120
4  -83.05915 42.32060
5  -83.05804 42.31984
6  -83.05711 42.31904
7  -83.05658 42.31851
8  -83.05592 42.31778
9  -83.05525 42.31695
10 -83.05458 42.31591
11 -83.05212 42.31150
12 -83.05171 42.31074
13 -83.05006 42.30802

[[2]]
         X1       X2
1 -83.16668 42.31032
2 -83.16782 42.30987

> length(dotz)
[1] 3674
```

My approach:

```
buff <- dotz[[1]]

for (i in 2:length(dotz)) {
  buff <- merge(buff, dotz[[i]], all = TRUE)
}
```

What would be the command that does the same, but more efficiently? Thanks. (I know, I could’ve pre-allocated the array size. In this case, it didn’t matter too much, and I am looking for a way that doesn’t involve a `for` loop anyway.)

Comment: You may try `rbindlist` from pacakge `data.table` and I think the solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34761693/how-to-bind-data-table-without-increasing-the-memory-consumption/34768285#34768285) can help too.

Comment: Try `do.call(rbind, dotz)` or `data.table::rbindlist(dotz)`

Comment: Thanks. `data.table::rbindlist(dotz)` was about 10x faster than `do.call`. Awesome.