# is it possible to process file reading and parsing in R

Tags: json, r, jsonlite

There are bunch of files in a directory that has json formatted entries in each line. The size of the files varies from 5k to 200MB. I have this code to go though each file, parse the data I am looking for in the json and finally form a data frame. This script is taking a very long time to finish, in fact it never finishes.

Is there any way to speed it up so that I can read the files faster?

Code:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(data.table) 

setwd("C:/Files/")

#data <- lapply(readLines("test.txt"), fromJSON)

df<-data.frame(Timestamp=factor(),Source=factor(),Host=factor(),Status=factor())
filenames <- list.files("Json_files", pattern="*.txt", full.names=TRUE)

for(i in filenames){
  print(i)
  data <- lapply(readLines(i), fromJSON)
  myDf <- do.call("rbind", lapply(data, function(d) { 
    data.frame(TimeStamp = d$payloadData$timestamp, 
               Source = d$payloadData$source, 
               Host = d$payloadData$host, 
               Status = d$payloadData$status)}))

  df<-rbind(df,myDf)
```

}

This is a sample entry but there are thousands of entries like this in the file:

```
{"senderDateTimeStamp":"2016/04/08 10:53:18","senderHost":null,"senderAppcode":"app","senderUsecase":"appinternalstats_prod","destinationTopic":"app_appinternalstats_realtimedata_topic","correlatedRecord":false,"needCorrelationCacheCleanup":false,"needCorrelation":false,"correlationAttributes":null,"correlationRecordCount":0,"correlateTimeWindowInMills":0,"lastCorrelationRecord":false,"realtimeESStorage":true,"receiverDateTimeStamp":1460127623591,"payloadData":{"timestamp":"2016-04-08T10:53:18.169","status":"get","source":"STREAM","fund":"JVV","client":"","region":"","evetid":"","osareqid":"","basis":"","pricingdate":"","content":"","msgname":"","recipient":"","objid":"","idlreqno":"","host":"WEB01","servermember":"test"},"payloadDataText":"","key":"app:appinternalstats_prod","destinationTopicName":"app_appinternalstats_realtimedata_topic","hdfsPath":"app/appinternalstats_prod","esindex":"app","estype":"appinternalstats_prod","useCase":"appinternalstats_prod","appCode":"app"}

{"senderDateTimeStamp":"2016/04/08 10:54:18","senderHost":null,"senderAppcode":"app","senderUsecase":"appinternalstats_prod","destinationTopic":"app_appinternalstats_realtimedata_topic","correlatedRecord":false,"needCorrelationCacheCleanup":false,"needCorrelation":false,"correlationAttributes":null,"correlationRecordCount":0,"correlateTimeWindowInMills":0,"lastCorrelationRecord":false,"realtimeESStorage":true,"receiverDateTimeStamp":1460127623591,"payloadData":{"timestamp":"2016-04-08T10:53:18.169","status":"get","source":"STREAM","fund":"JVV","client":"","region":"","evetid":"","osareqid":"","basis":"","pricingdate":"","content":"","msgname":"","recipient":"","objid":"","idlreqno":"","host":"WEB02","servermember":""},"payloadDataText":"","key":"app:appinternalstats_prod","destinationTopicName":"app_appinternalstats_realtimedata_topic","hdfsPath":"app/appinternalstats_prod","esindex":"app","estype":"appinternalstats_prod","useCase":"appinternalstats_prod","appCode":"app"}

{"senderDateTimeStamp":"2016/04/08 10:55:18","senderHost":null,"senderAppcode":"app","senderUsecase":"appinternalstats_prod","destinationTopic":"app_appinternalstats_realtimedata_topic","correlatedRecord":false,"needCorrelationCacheCleanup":false,"needCorrelation":false,"correlationAttributes":null,"correlationRecordCount":0,"correlateTimeWindowInMills":0,"lastCorrelationRecord":false,"realtimeESStorage":true,"receiverDateTimeStamp":1460127623591,"payloadData":{"timestamp":"2016-04-08T10:53:18.169","status":"get","source":"STREAM","fund":"JVV","client":"","region":"","evetid":"","osareqid":"","basis":"","pricingdate":"","content":"","msgname":"","recipient":"","objid":"","idlreqno":"","host":"WEB02","servermember":""},"payloadDataText":"","key":"app:appinternalstats_prod","destinationTopicName":"app_appinternalstats_realtimedata_topic","hdfsPath":"app/appinternalstats_prod","esindex":"app","estype":"appinternalstats_prod","useCase":"appinternalstats_prod","appCode":"app"}
```

Comment: @Tensibai, I've place a sample entry but the files can have 10'of thousands of entries like this.

Comment: You can count the number of rows in the files, which would give you a good estimate of the size of the final dataset. R doesn't handle growing objects very well. You should try to avoid the `rbind` calls.

Comment: @Tensibai, sorry, I just placed 3 entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your example data in "c:/tmp.txt":

```
> df <- jsonlite::fromJSON(paste0("[",paste0(readLines("c:/tmp.txt"),collapse=","),"]"))$payloadData[c("timestamp","source","host","status")]
> df
                timestamp source  host status
1 2016-04-08T10:53:18.169 STREAM WEB01    get
2 2016-04-08T10:53:18.169 STREAM WEB02    get
3 2016-04-08T10:53:18.169 STREAM WEB02    get
```

So to adapt your code to get a list of dataframes:

```
dflist <- lapply(filenames, function(i) {
  jsonlite::fromJSON(
    paste0("[",
            paste0(readLines(i),collapse=","),
            "]")
  )$payloadData[c("timestamp","source","host","status")]
})
```

The idea is to transform your lines (from `readLines`) into a big json array and then create the dataframe by parsing it as json.

As lmo already showcased, using lapply on your filenmaes list procide you with a list of dataframes, if you really want only one dataframe at end you can load the `data.table` packages and then use `rbindlist` on `dflist` to get only one dataframe.

Or if you're short in memory [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34761693/how-to-bind-data-table-without-increasing-the-memory-consumption/) may help you.

Comment: @Tendibai, your solution is working the faster. How do I convert dflist to data frame?

Comment: @user1471980 either `largedf <- do.cal("rbind",dflist)` or `rbindlist`from data.table package

Comment: @Tenibai, I know you answered this question but what if there were nested objects within the payloaddata section like this: ""payloadData":{"timestamp":"2016-04-07T00:00:00.093","beat":{"name":"server1","hostname":"server1"},"count":"1","shipper":"server1","mem":{"total":"18855256064","free":"7273639936","actual_used":"3755769856","used_p":"0.6242380717975277","actual_free":"15099486208","used":"11581616128","actual_used_p":"0.2091895439262065"}", how would I iterate though each nested objects here like beat and mem and grab the hostname within beat and actual_used with mem?

Comment: write a new question referencing this one and link it here ;) comments are awfull for code. I'm heading back home,  may have a look tomorow if no-one answers before

Comment: thank you for your help, here is the link to the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629362/how-do-you-extract-data-from-nested-json-data-in-r

Answer (score 1):

One speed up is to replace your `for` loop with `lapply` Then drop the final `rbind`. the speed up here would be that R would not have to repeatedly copy an increasingly large file, df over your "bunch" of files.  The result would be stored in a convenient list that you could either use as is or convert to a data.frame in one go:

```
# create processing function
getData <- function(i) {
  print(i)
  data <- lapply(readLines(i), fromJSON)
  myDf <- do.call("rbind", lapply(data, function(d) { 
  data.frame(TimeStamp = d$payloadData$timestamp, 
           Source = d$payloadData$source, 
           Host = d$payloadData$host, 
           Status = d$payloadData$status)}))
}

# lapply over files
myDataList <- lapply(filenames, getData)
```