# Extract tidy data from complex nested JSON in R

Tags: r, json, tidyverse

Extracting tidy data from a simple JSON is trivial with the `tidyjson` package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyjson/vignettes/introduction-to-tidyjson.html)

I haven't been able to apply this logic to a complex nested JSON structure. Similar question such as this one ([how do you extract data from nested json data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629362/how-do-you-extract-data-from-nested-json-data-in-r)) are too specific so I can't extrapolate it to other cases.

A more general case could be given by this structure (see working reproducible examples here: 1.4 Example requests: https://www.ree.es/en/apidatos)

```
{
        "data": {
          "type": "WIDGET TYPE",
          "id": "WIDGET_ID",
          "attributes": {
            "title": "WIDGET NAME",
            "last-update": "2019-02-01T08:26:34.000+01:00",
            "description": "WIDGET DESCRIPTION",
          },
          "meta": {
            "cache-control": {
              "cache": "HIT",
              "expireAt": "2019-03-01T17:18:22"
            }
          }
        },
        "included": [
          {
            "type": "INDICATOR_1 TYPE",
            "id": "INDICADOR_1_ID",
            "groupId": null,
            "attributes": {
              "title": "INDICADOR_1 NAME",
              "description": "INDICADOR_1 DESCRIPTION",
              "color": "#2fa688",
              "type": "INDICADOR_1 TYPE",
              "magnitude": "INDICADOR_1 MAGNITUDE",
              "composite": false,
              "last-update": "2019-02-19T08:26:34.000+01:00",
              "values": [
                {
                  "value": 12345,
                  "percentage": "VALUE BETWEEN 0 AND 1",
                  "datetime": "2019-02-04T20:44:00.000+01:00"
                }
              ]
            },
           {
            "type": "INDICATOR_2 TYPE",
            "id": "INDICADOR_1_ID",
            "groupId": null,
            "attributes": {
               …
            }
          }
        ]
       }
      }
```

1. The first level has an object `"data"` and an array `"included"`
2. The `"included"` array has one object for each indicator
3. In each of these objects there is an `"attributes"` object with a `"values"` array where the final data are located: `"value"`, `"percentage"` and `"datetime"`

The goal would be to extract the data to a tidy dataframe with the columns `"type"`, `"title"`, `"value"`, `"percentage"` and `"datetime"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out after a lot of trial and error. I answer myself in case it can help anyone else departing from the `json` object:

```
library(tidyjson)

json %>% # our json object
  enter_object(included) %>% # to enter the object where the data are
  gather_array() %>% spread_all() %>% # to work with the array
  select(attributes.title) %>% # to maintain this variable
  enter_object(values) %>% # to enter the array where the final data are
  gather_array() %>% spread_all() %>% # same as before to work with the array
  select(indicator = attributes.title, value, percentage, datetime) # select final data
```

Basically it's the same process `enter_object %>% gather_array %>% spread_all %>% select` repeated twice. You only have to name the objects you want to enter on each level and the pieces of information you want to select.