# Remove blank counts in a list of xtabs

Tags: r

I'm working with the following data:

```
CommPref<-structure(list(`Email/Newsletter` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
"E-newsletters/email"), class = "factor"), PrintMail = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("", "Printed newsletters/direct mail"), class = "factor"), 
Fax = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("", "Faxed updates"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Email/Newsletter", 
"PrintMail", "Fax"), row.names = c(NA, -130L), class = "data.frame")
```

And when I apply `list.of.xtabs<-lapply(CommPref,function(x) xtabs(~x+SD[,12]))` I get the desired result, however, due to some of the data collection, there is often a row with a frequency count of the blanks. With the resulting `list.of.xtabs`, what's the easiest way of removing the blank counts?

Comment: Do you know how to remove that row from a single element of `list.of.xtabs`? If you know it, just `lapply` the same thing to all the list. Also, take a look at the `na.action` and `exclude` arguments of `xtabs`.

Comment: I came across this [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652136/how-can-i-remove-an-element-from-a-list) but wasn't sure how to apply it. I just used `exclude=""` with success though.

Comment: Followup question. In the resulting `list.of.xtabs` there are two columns that repeat themselves the `x` and the `...SD...12` columns. Is there a way to limit those too, s that the end structure looks more like col1=years,col2:n=freq?