# How do I remove an invisible data frame which I create from a list?

Tags: r

```
a<- data.frame(x=runif(10), y = runif(10), Acc = 1)
b<- data.frame(x=runif(10), y = runif(10), Acc = 0)
ls<- list(a,b)
```

When I type `ls[[1]]` and `ls[[2]]`, it prints the respective data frames. `class(ls[1])` and `class(ls[2])` shows me they are list. `class(ls[[1]])` and `class(ls[[2]])` shows me they are data frames. However when I type `rm(ls[1])` or `rm(ls[[1]])`, I get the following error :

> Error in rm(ls[1]) : ... must contain names or character strings.

I never see these kind of data frames which I create by a list in the environment window of R Studio. If I use `rm(list=ls())`, I can remove everything without retaining what I want.
How shall remove `ls[[1]]` and `ls[[2]]`?

Comment: `ls[[1]]<-NULL` or `ls[[2]]<-NULL`

Comment: you are trying to remove a list object here so you can try `ls[-1]` or `ls[-2]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652136/how-can-i-remove-an-element-from-a-list

Comment: Thanks @moh3n ls[[1]]=NULL works, but if I type both 1 ls[[1]] followed by ls[[2]] it first deletes the second one Error in ls[[2]] : subscript out of bounds and then typing ls[1] deletes the first one. May be it is a matter of time or I am making a mistake

Comment: @ARIMITRAMAITI You have a list with two elements. If you delete one of the elements, how many elements are in the result? Indexing in R allways begins with index 1.